# Wordpress asking users for FTP information

Tags: php, wordpress, ftp

I have noticed that when testing our website that wordpress is asking for FTP information, there is no explanation why and I have seen this happen on my own logged out sessions. What is this and how can I stop wordpress from doing this?

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about Wordpress administration and not programming. It should be asked on [Wordpress.SE](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea it existed! Appreciate the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when WP doesn't have the permission to edit a file or write in a folder. Make sure the folders are 0755, files 0644 and the owner is correct.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look... its very odd since it happens to users who are browsing the website.

Comment: Thanks, that wasn't the issue. Not too sure how to fix this.